# Android Compose MVVM multi network call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I started using Jetpack Compose by adapting one of my clean architecture applications. I created a bottom navigation bar with this compose function :

```
@Composable
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController){
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = NavigationItem.Planes.route) {
        composable(NavigationItem.Planes.route) {
            PlanesScreen(hiltViewModel())
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.Weather.route) {
            WeatherScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.More.route) {
            MoreScreen()
        }
    }

}
```

In my `PlanesScreen` I use the Hilt method to pass it the following `ViewModel`:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PlanesViewModel @Inject constructor(private val planeInfoUseCase: PlaneInfoUseCase) : ViewModel() {

    fun planeInfo() : LiveData<UiResponse<ArrayList<PlaneInfo>>> {
        return planeInfoUseCase.execute().toUiResponse().flowAsLiveData(Dispatchers.IO)
    }    
}
```

The `useCase` returns a `Flow` which I transform into `UiResponse` to represent the different states of my view :

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.toUiResponse() : Flow<UiResponse<T>>{
    return this.map<T, UiResponse<T>> { UiResponse.Success(it) }
        .onStart { emit(UiResponse.Loading()) }
        .catch {
            val t : Throwable = it
            emit(UiResponse.Error(it))
        }
}
```

The `PlaneScreen` screen contains a composable method which displays text without any constraints

```
@Composable
fun PlanesScreen(viewModel : PlanesViewModel){
    PlaneList(viewModel.planeInfo().observeAsState())
}
```

I transform the `LiveData` into `State` via `observeAsSate` then I pass it to the method that will display the text.

In this one I perform my when on my `UiResponse` in order to react to the different state of the response

```
@Composable
fun PlaneList(state: State<UiResponse<ArrayList<PlaneInfo>>?>){

    state.value.let {
        when(it){
            is UiResponse.Error ->  Text(text = "Error")
            is UiResponse.Loading -> Text(text = "Loading")
            is UiResponse.Success -> it.data.forEach { Text(text = it.registration) }
        }
    }

}
```

When I compile the application, the screen contains the text `Loading`, then the result of the printing of the list, but when I look at Chuck I have two calls to my database.

While using the debugger I noticed that the composable of my `NavHost` which launches the `PlaneScreen` is called twice, which causes my problem.

No matter how much I looked, I couldn't find a solution in order to be able to pass a `ViewModel` to a composable in a `NavHost` and make only one call even when the screen is recompose

Do you have any idea how I could fix this problem without having to pass the `viewModels` to my `Navigation` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I was going through a function in my ViewModel, rather than a variable:

```
fun planeInfo() : LiveData<UiResponse<ArrayList<PlaneInfo>>> {
    return planeInfoUseCase.execute().toUiResponse().flowAsLiveData(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

I changed this to:

```
val planeInfo : LiveData<UiResponse<ArrayList<PlaneInfo>>> = planeInfoUseCase.execute().toUiResponse().flowAsLiveData(Dispatchers.IO)
```

I always wondered why go through variables in the ViewModel, I have the answer now.